# How to model this object?

Tags: cad, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a 3d model of this showerhead holder [image: showerhead holder]

I did this STL file using cadquery:

```
import math

import cadquery as cq

height = 15
width = 32
rect_length = 30

inner_radius = 10.5
inner_circle_offset = rect_length + 10
outer_radius = 16
outer_circle_offset = rect_length + 8

triangle_base = 18 * 1.2
triangle_height = 14 * 1.2

wp = cq.Workplane("XY")

rect = wp.rect(width, outer_circle_offset, (0, 0)).extrude(height)
outer_circle = (
    wp.circle(outer_radius).extrude(height).translate((width / 2, outer_circle_offset))
)
inner_circle = (
    wp.circle(inner_radius).extrude(height).translate((width / 2, inner_circle_offset))
)
triangle = (
    wp.polyline(
        [
            (width / 2, outer_circle_offset),
            (width / 2 - triangle_base / 2, outer_circle_offset + triangle_height),
            (width / 2 + triangle_base / 2, outer_circle_offset + triangle_height),
        ]
    )
    .close()
    .extrude(height)
)

base = rect.union(outer_circle).cut(inner_circle).cut(triangle)


wp = cq.Workplane("YZ")
x, y = 12, 9
P1 = (0, y)
P2 = (x, height)
P3 = (0, height)
faucet_curve = (
    wp.moveTo(*P1).sagittaArc(P2, -0.8).lineTo(*P3).lineTo(*P1).close().extrude(width)
)

base = base.cut(faucet_curve)


screw_head_height = 3
screw_head_radius = 4
screw_radius = 2.5
screw_head_offset = 10

wp = cq.Workplane("XY")
screw_head = (
    wp.moveTo(width / 2, screw_head_offset)
    .circle(screw_head_radius)
    .extrude(screw_head_height)
)

screw = wp.moveTo(width / 2, screw_head_offset).circle(screw_radius).extrude(height)
base = base.cut(screw_head).cut(screw)

tip_radius = 5.8
tip_height = 6
tip_angle = -20

wp = cq.Workplane("XY").workplane(offset=tip_height)
tip_circle = wp.moveTo(width / 2, screw_head_offset).circle(tip_radius).extrude(height)
tip_rect = (
    wp.moveTo(width / 2, screw_head_offset)
    .rect(2 * tip_radius, -2 * screw_head_offset, centered=(True, False))
    .extrude(height)
)
tip = tip_circle.union(tip_rect)
tip = tip.rotate(
    (width / 2, screw_head_offset, 0), (width / 2, screw_head_offset, height), tip_angle
)
base = base.cut(tip)

cq.exporters.export(base, "holder.stl")
```

[image: my cad model]

My main problem is to reproduce the curve around the screw hole. I tried using Blender bevel tool but I would prefer something reproducible and parametric, so that I can adjust the parameters manually.

Comment: If I'm recognizing the curve you seek, would it be practical to consider it as a radius and not a bevel? The top portion is a simple radius on a flat surface, but I'm not so sure how the descending curved portions would take a radius.

Comment: @fred_dot_u The bevel tool on Blender can do shapes. My problem is exactly with the descending curved portions...

Comment: Draw a line on the surface then its easier for you to decipher this. anyway photogrammetry is your friend. Anyway does it really matter?